# Angular capacitor app crashes on firebase login due to redirect

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, capacitor

Im using Angular2 and Capacitor for a project testing out capacitor. I use Firebase for login and every time I try login it crashes the capacitor project on android.
It seems that the crash happens around the redirect/popup. I firstly tried the `signInwithPopup()`. I found out that this was not supported within mobile environments so I moved to the `signInWithRedirect`

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
   console.log('result', result);
});
```

This also crashes as it returns `{user: null}` but it works on browser and on browser both methods work.
Another method Ive seen from the ionic forums is that the `getRedirectResult` should be moved to the `ngOnInit` so that when the redirect returns to the page you listen for the redirect straight away but this also doesnt work. Has anyone impemented this in Capacitor using Angular2 project?
 Any help or ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Can you try with latest beta? There was a similar error that was crashing the app

Comment: @jcesarmobile works perfect with the new update thanks. You can add this as an answer and ill accept the answer

Comment: @Dennington-bear did the above code worked for you exactly that way ? I tried but that didn't work for me. can you please share what you did for android ? thank you

Comment: @NadhirFalta the normal Firebase code will work it seems you will have to look into the dynamic links on the Firebase console. I got moved onto another project since and never got around to this. Thats my two cents on how to continue dev for there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bug in that version, it’s fixed in latest beta (17)